tracker.init throws Unknown C++ exception from OpenCV
I wrote a program to test opencv trackers but I got error. Here is my python code using opencv 4.10.0:
import cv2

video_path = '.../v1.mp4'
video = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

tracker = cv2.TrackerDaSiamRPN()

if not video.isOpened():
    print("Could not open video")

# Read first frame.
ok, frame = video.read()
if not ok:
    print('Cannot read video file')

frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
roi = cv2.selectROI(frame, True)

tracker.init(frame, roi)

and this is the error message:

File "...\opencv_trackers.py", line 19, in 
tracker.init(frame, roi) cv2.error: Unknown C++ exception from OpenCV code


You are missing while/else and waitKey()

ignore Supra. he's known for suggesting nonsense. in this case it's nonsense because you have no imshow() call, so you have no use for a waitKey(). there is also no need for "while/else" (?!?!) if you just want a single frame. -- you could simplify the situation by loading a single image from an image file. it probably makes no difference though.

if my answer helped you, please mark it as "accepted". [tour]

Docs of cv::TrackerDaSiamRPN suggest that you must call the create() static method to get an instance. You can't instantiate it the regular way.
tracker = cv.TrackerDaSiamRPN.create()

You can optionally call create() with a TrackerDaSiamRPN::Params object. The docs on that Params class are useless, so if you're interested in that, you'd want to browse the "samples" directories in OpenCV's source tree.
